# C#-WinForm - How to close parent form when child is closed?

Tags: forms, parent

This is my issue:

I have 3 forms:

- Form fParent
- Form fChild
- Form OpenForm

I want that When I click a button on Form fChild, it shows Form OpenFormand and hides Form fParentand Form fChild.

How can I do that?
Please help me.

Comment: //this is code on fChild

OpenForm frm = new OpenForm();
this.Hide();
frm.Show();

I dont know how to close fParent.
Thanks and best regards

Answer (score 0):

Create new object of parent form and close/Hide it. Call `Hide()` method if you want to hide parent form, or `Close()` method if you want to close parent form.

Answer (score 0):

The best way for you to do this is create a singleton class, because if you keep on doing this,

```
Form1 f1 = new Form1();
f1.Show();
this.Hide();
```

you keep on instantiating a new form and not going back to the previous form

here's how you do singleton design pattern:

```
public static class SingletonForm
{
  private static Form1 _f1;
  private static Form2 _f2;

  public static Form1 _Form1
   {
     get
     {
         if(_f1 == null)
          {
             _f1 = new Form1();
          }
          return _f1;
     }
   }

public static Form2 _Form2
   {
     get
     {
         if(_f2 == null)
          {
             _f2 = new Form2();
          }
          return _f2;
     }
   }
}
```

in your button click in form just call:

```
SingletonForm._Form1.Hide();
SingletonForm._Form2.ShowDialog();
```

Comment: Thanks JC, but you can say it clearly. please? Thanks and best regards

Comment: this class is actually a design pattern used to instantiate a class ONCE, it's most useful in navigation through forms. In this case, when you call the class in the form, it will first check if the form is already open, if it's open it will no longer create a new Form instance but instead open the form that's hidden which is still running in the background

Comment: here's a link for preference about singleton design pattern, there are many kinds of design patterns used in C#.Net, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff650316.aspx

Comment: I didn't gave you the exact solution for you to learn, this site is not for asking codes, but i gave you the proper logic. Learn from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Assembly frmAssembly = Assembly.LoadFile(Application.ExecutablePath);
            foreach (Type type in frmAssembly.GetTypes())
            {
                if (type.BaseType == typeof(Form))
                {
                    if (type.Name == formname))
                    {
                        Form frmshow = (Form)frmAssembly.CreateInstance(type.ToString());

                        foreach (Form form in this.MdiChildren)
                        {
                              form.Close();   // form close or hide
                        }
                        frmshow.Show();
                    }
                }
            }
```